# Jenkins and SonarQube matching authentication

Tags: plugins, jenkins, ldap, sonarqube

I am setting up a CI/CD system at my company based on Jenkins and SonarQube and I already integrated LDAP in both. I am using [Role based plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin) in Jenkins and the problem is Jenkins allows me (as Administrator) to assign user to a specific role **without requiring that user to login Jenkins in advance**. But Sonar with LDAP **only create users after logging in**, which leads to having to ask at least 8 people (for each project) to go to my Sonar Server page first for authorization. Here's my question: Is there any tools/plugins to match authentication on Jenkins and Sonar, such as people config their own projects on Jenkins can also view bugs/config their projects on Sonar? I appreciate any alternative suggestions. My thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no tool or plugin doing this for you. You can assign groups to the user per project and use them in SonarQube to assign the projects.

Or you can create the users manually for SonarQube ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3631898/390177)):

> - Write directly to the database (there is a simple table called users).
> - Write a java application that depends on the sonar plugin API, you can then use constructor injection to get a Sonar hibernate session
>     and persist the user you want. See [Here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Documentation#Codingaplugin-Howtoreuseexistingcomponents%3F).

Comment: Better than directly mucking with the database is to use SonarQube's webservice API. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18212210/382885